# Delaminating roof sheathing in attic

Tags: roof, attic, sheathing

I recently had my roof replaced. The roofer recommended that we also replace the sheathing so we did. As they were installing the sheathing I expressed concern that the sheathing had small strips where the top layer was missing. The roofer shrugged it off and said that new wood sheathing is not as good as it was decades ago. He installed the damaged looking pieces. Now many months later I went into the attic and see the top layer of the plywood peeling off in places. I think the plywood that he installed was bad. The roofer installed state of the art ventilation with a ridge vent and an intake vent along the gutter line. Can the peeling sheathing be repaired? Do I have to redo the roof shingles?

Comment: How about a photo or two?  But generally I'd say that the plywood should not be delaminating.

Comment: Yeah, delamination might indicate that he used interior grade plywood, not exterior grade with waterproof glue. That could be very bad. There should be stamps on the plywood itself indicating the rating of it.